# Ubuntu 16.04 Incredibly Slow in i5 8GB RAM Dell Inspiron n4050

Tags: performance

I have a Dell Laptop Inspiron N4050 with a Intel Core i5 -2450M CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4

I used to Run Linux Mint 17, and it was fine. I decided to move to Ubuntu 16.04, clean install. But my system runs amazingly slow.
It takes about 10 seconds to open a terminal window!

I have no idea what could be causing this. CPU usage and Memory usages seem to be fine. Also, i checked the **Additional Drivers** setting, but it shows no drivers to download.

I know this laptop has an integrated Intel GPU, but I haven't installed anything. What could it be?

Answer (score 3):

**SOLVED**
A new clean install solved the issue. I think it was probably a disk failure. I had many disk errors when opening gparted. So i deleted all partitions on my HD, rebuild the partition table, and formated new partitions. 
Ubuntu running nice and fast now. Didn't even install intel graphics.